# Why does pattern matching on a union have an unreachable pattern warning?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

Given the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/items/unions.html), I cannot understand why the pattern matching on a union doesn't work properly:

```
union A {
    a1: i32,
    a2: f32,
}

struct B(A);
let b = B(A { a2: 1.0 });
unsafe {
    match b.0 {
        A { a1 } => println!("int"),
        A { a2 } => println!("float"),
    }
}
```

[Outputs "int" with an unreachable warning](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c4b0a312f808e13c5ebc6844b4318d8b&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015).

```
warning: unreachable pattern
  --> src/main.rs:12:13
   |
12 |             A { a2 } => println!("float"),
   |             ^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: #[warn(unreachable_patterns)] on by default
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *entire* point of a `union` is that the compiler doesn't store any information in the `union` about what type it is; it's **completely up to the programmer**. Because of this, there's no information for a `match` to use to decide what type the value is.

Because of this, your code is conceptually equivalent to

```
struct A {
    a1: i32,
}

let b = A { a1: 42 };

match b {
    A { a1 } => println!("int {}", a1),
    A { a1 } => println!("float {}", a1),
}
```

There's no case in which the second match arm will ever be executed.

In fact, switching back and forth between the fields is a prime usage of a `union`:

```
union A {
    i: i32,
    f: f32,
}

let a = A { i: 42 };
let b = unsafe { a.f };

println!("{}", b);
```

---

You may wish to use an `enum` if you want the compiler to keep track of what variant you have. In some contexts, enums are called *tagged unions* because that's exactly what they are: a union with a tag alongside to identify what the union contains.

Otherwise, you need to track what type is actually in the union in some other manner. One such way is to implement your own tag:

```
union A {
    a1: i32,
    a2: f32,
}

struct B {
    is_int: bool,
    data: A,
}

let b = B {
    is_int: false,
    data: A { a2: 1.0 },
};

unsafe {
    match b {
        B {
            is_int: true,
            data: A { a1 },
        } => println!("int {}", a1),
        B {
            is_int: false,
            data: A { a2 },
        } => println!("float {}", a2),
    }
}
```

The tag can be anything you can match on:

```
union A {
    a1: i32,
    a2: f32,
}

struct B {
    kind: Kind,
    data: A,
}

enum Kind {
    Int,
    Float,
}

let b = B {
    kind: Kind::Float,
    data: A { a2: 1.0 },
};

unsafe {
    match b {
        B {
            kind: Kind::Int,
            data: A { a1 },
        } => println!("int {}", a1),
        B {
            kind: Kind::Float,
            data: A { a2 },
        } => println!("float {}", a2),
    }
}
```

I suppose you could even use an enum *around* the union...

```
union A {
    a1: i32,
    a2: f32,
}

enum B {
    Int(A),
    Float(A),
}

let b = B::Float(A { a2: 1.0 });

unsafe {
    match b {
        B::Int(A { a1 }) => println!("int {}", a1),
        B::Float(A { a2 }) => println!("float {}", a2),
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for editing my question! I cannot change the union. Can I use `std::any::TypeId` then?

Comment: Sure, but assume union has a lot of fields, then your suggestion is not really feasible!

Comment: Maybe instead of `is_int` can store `type_id` and match against that?

Comment: *Why* would you want to use `TypeId`, which can literally be any possible type ever, instead of a small fixed set (as is shown)?

Comment: As I said, I don't think it's a good idea to repeat every type in the union when it has 100 different fields and types for example!

Comment: Although my suggestion is more hypothetical than practical I suppose!

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani If you have a union with **100 possibilities** you have bigger problems. Regardless, I'd *still* say that enforcing more things statically is better. If that's not a goal of yours, then Rust *may* not be a good fit for you or the problem you are attempting to solve.

Comment: @EhsanM.Kermani Also, if you have a union with two possibilities of the same type, then it seems like `TypeId` will be unusable.